# Login problem after installing my written plugin

Tags: plugins, login, dashboard

I have create a simple widget plugin, it's so simple and it make no changes in cookie setting, also it work great in my local site , but in the host i have a problem after activate this plugin and try to login the WordPress again, it says:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser.

or a whitepage show after logging in, and dashboard do not appear.

after deactivating the plugin every thing will work correctly!

what is the problem? is there any thing that i must add to my plugin for setting an special cookie?

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-1

Comment: tnx @stealthyninja , but I tried all this ways before,they didn't worked for me.

Comment: @s_ha_dum this is nor syntax error and nor restricted access and also nor hosting issues, and in fact it's not a localized problem(question), so many body have this problem but there is not a right way to solve, I almost searched all the forums and support site but just this solution has helped me! why you mark this question as off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I have found the answer, the answer is in this link:

[How To Fix The WordPress White Screen of Death (Theme/Plugin Error)](http://www.jewishcommentator.com/wordpress-white-screen-of-death-fix)

the answer is too odd! that was happened because new line character(enter) between close and open tag of php...like this:
[image: in the line 11 you can see an example]

in the line 11 you can see an example, when it have been delete every thing have been right!

Comment: And that is another good reason not to overuse-- aka abuse-- those PHP tags.